# top.window.location not working in IE

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer

I have a facebook app that asks for permissions from the user if the user's fb id is 0 as such

```
        if ($fbid == 0) {
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "email", "redirect_uri" => $redirect_uri.'?sk=app_'.$app_id));
            die('<script>top.window.location='.json_encode($login_url).'</script>');
        } else {
            $country_code = $_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE'];
            if($country_code == "RE"){
                header("Location: checks.php");
                die();
            }else {
                header("Location: wrong-country.php");
                die();
            }
        }
```

It works well in every browser except IE which just prints this on the screen top.window.location=http://facebookloginurlhere.com

Is there something i'm doing wrong? Why would top.window.location not work?

Answer (score 0):

You would not have permission to change the top location.

Try instead

```
window.open("'.$login_url.'","_top");
```

Alternatively your issue could be a header - if you do not set the header in the PHP to mime type text/html, it would be text/plain and IE could decide to just print the string